# Jaydata toLiveArray() error "Pure Class" w/ IndexedDB provider

Tags: angularjs, jaydata

Using Jaydata, I can populate my simple local database from an odata service. The database has an Organization table.

I am also using AngularJs. The following code gets the organizations from the local database and binds them to $scope.Organizations which is referenced on my OrganziationIndex view. I've tested this so far in Chrome, Safari on iOS7, and the Android browser built in to ICS, and it works as expected in each of those browsers.

```
var localDB = new InspecTechDB({
    name: 'local',
    databaseName: 'InspecTech'
});

app.controller('OrganizationIndex', function ($scope, $data) {

    $scope.organizations = [];

    //wait until the localDB is ready, then get the Organizations
    $.when(localDB.onReady())
    .then(function () {
        $scope.inspectechdb = localDB;
        $scope.organizations = localDB.Organizations.toLiveArray();
        $scope.message = "Organizations fetched from local store. Click one of them!";
    });

});
```

However, in IE11, I get an error message on the console that states simply "Pure Class" on this line and the organizations are not listed on the view:

```
scope.organizations = localDB.Organizations.toLiveArray();
```

A Google search reveals literally no results: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jaydata%20tolivearray%20error%20%22pure%20class%22)

I've verified with console logging that the table is populated from the odata service. What I have found is that if I change the code as shown below (changed from local database to odata service), that the error goes away:

```
var remoteDB = new InspecTechDB({
    name: 'oData',
    oDataServiceHost: '/odata'
});

app.controller('OrganizationIndex', function ($scope, $data) {

    $scope.organizations = [];

    //wait until the localDB is ready, then get the Organizations
    $.when(remoteDB.onReady())
    .then(function () {
        $scope.inspectechdb = remoteDB;
        $scope.organizations = remoteDB.Organizations.toLiveArray();
        $scope.message = "Organizations fetched from local store. Click one of them!";
    });

});
```

I do intend for the application to be run offline so I need to be able to get the organizations from the local database and not the odata service.

Can someone point in the right direction for what I need to do to make this work in IE?

Thanks,
Mike

UPDATE 1:
I'm observing the same error in Firefox.

UPDATE 2:
I'm observing the same error in Chrome if I change the provider like so:

```
var localDB = new InspecTechDB({
    name: 'indexedDb',
    databaseName: 'InspecTech'
});
```

So the problem is not specific to IE, more like specific to the IndexedDB provider.

UDPATE 3:
Here's some workaround code. I'd still like to know about the problem with .toLiveArray().

```
var localDB = new InspecTechDB({
    name: 'local',
    databaseName: 'InspecTech'
});

app.controller('OrganizationIndex', function ($scope, $data) {


    $scope.organizations = [];

    //wait until the localDB is ready, then get the Organizations

    //$.when(localDB.onReady())
    //.then(function () {
    //    $scope.inspectechdb = localDB;
    //    $scope.organizations = localDB.Organizations.toLiveArray()
    //    .then(function () {
    //        $scope.message = "Organizations fetched from local store. Click one of them!";
    //    });
    //});

    //this code replaces the above code since I can't make toLiveArray work w/ indexedDB provider
    $.when(localDB.onReady())
        .then(function () {
            var organizations = localDB.Organizations.toArray();

            return $.when(organizations)
                    .then(function (orgs) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            orgs.forEach(function (organization) {
                                $scope.organizations.push(organization);
                            });
                        });
                    });
        });

});
```

Comment: If you take a look at the angularjs module you will find that it almost does the same as your workaround code. Any error on the console?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It looks like you really keep an eye out for these Jaydata questions! You helped me out earlier on this same little project; I really appreciate it. There is no error in any of the tested browsers with the workaround. I am content to continue w/ my workaround code; the .toLiveArray just seemed cleaner to me.